# hibernate HQL date difference

Tags: java, hibernate, date, hql

I want to find all records which maps to object XYZ with following conditions
A has date field XyzDateTime (its a time stamp)
Now currentTime -xyzDateTime  > 20 i want to select the record

```
query = session.creatQuery(Select x from XYZ where :currentTime-xyzDateTime > 20 )
query.setParameter("currentTime",new Date())
```

is this correct?  
 Can i check date difference in this way?

Comment: "is this correct?" - well what does it return when you run it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not correct. Simplest solution is like that (not the prettiest solution at all)

```
Date twentyDaysInFuture = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20).getTime());

query = session.createQuery("SELECT x FROM XYZ x WHERE xyzDateTime > :endDate").setParameter("endDate", twentyDaysInFuture);
```

Comment: new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 86400000 * 12) is even simpler - nor really pretty though

Comment: @Konstantin Pribluda: All problems have obvious, simple and wrong answers.